# Czech symbols changed into gibberish

Tags: windows, encoding, textfiles

I have this bizarre problem with Windows 10 Home edition. When I open some basic text file, `.srt` or `.txt` for example, it has different encoding. I guess it's because of different encoding since I am a Czech I need czech symbols:

**ě,š,č,ř,ť,ž, ň** and so on,

that means Unicode, Windows-1250 or ISO Latin 2.

I tried to change OS language - didn't help.
Looking through options in Chrome was useless as well - I have no problem while browsing. Downloading text files with IE, Opera or Firefox brought same results.
I am downloading them manually from site dedicated to subbing movies and series.

- When I downloaded text file on different computer the czech symbols were fine.
- Sending downloaded file through mail, Facebook
- or transferring it via flash disk changed czech symbol into gibberish.
  For example "ě" was saved in the file as "?", "č" was "è", etc. Even compressed text file was changed when I opened it.

Comment: Windows cannot guess the encoding of a text file because that information is not stored in the file, so it must use the current codepage. Better use Notepad++ and select the encoding manually and convert to Unicode. If you have MS Word it can guess the encoding quite effectively

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10, unlike earlier Windows versions, doesn't come with much in the way of language support.

You need to get the language packs you require individually from the Language Control Panel.

See https://support.microsoft.com/help/14236/language-packs for details regarding each language source.

Comment: I have already downloaded czech language package and set it as default, yet the problem still persist. I am quite clueless in this situation.

Comment: @Alorain you must also change to Czech locale or Windows will use the default codepage

Answer (score 0):

If it displays the wrong character then its either not UTF-8 but it its being interpreted as UTF-8 or it is UTF-8 but it is not displaying it as uni-code.

Unicode assigns a unique code point to all characters if you have a UTF-8 encoding and it results in a code-point for which I do not have a glyph then my windows 10 displays this glyph [image: missingglyph]
If the code point is not valid then my windows 10 displays [image: Unknown].

Since you are getting incorrect characters- rather than unknown - I think the encoding is not being properly interpreted.  So I think ensure all files are UTF-8 and that both machines are treating the files as UTF-8.

UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode, however Windows-1250 or ISO Latin 2 are code pages which interpret the same byte sequences as different characters.